# Looking for a solution for a conditional class binding in the existing project

Tags: vue.js

I have a child component in an existing Vue project that I would like to extend. I want to give the possibility to add custom classes to the child component. Normally I would add `:class="customClasses"` to the dom-element. But there is already a conditional classbinding done in the ChildCoponente. And two same attributes are not allowed (for Example: `<... :class="customClass" :class="{'bg-red': conditionA}" ...>`). So I don't know how to mix both right now.

It's a Vue 3 project but the corresponding component uses the Vue Option Api.

**Question:** How can i bind the customClass prop to the anchor tag?

```js
<template>
    <a :href="linkTo" class="dropdown-item" :class="{'bg-red': conditionA}" :tabindex="disabled ? '-1' : undefined" @click="click">
        <slot></slot>
    </a>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "DropdownItem",

        props: {
            linTo: {
                default: '#'
            },
            conditionA: {
                default: false,
            },

            customClass: {
                default: null
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Easy way: (recommended)** You can use the class attribute from the ChildElement in your Parent Component.

```js
// PARENT
<template>
  <div>
    <child-component class="your customm classes which you want pass" />
  </div>
</template>
```

And vue will do the magic and adding the classes to your child.

**Long way:**
You can pass an array of objects instead only a object. `:class="[customClass, {'some-class': comeConidtion}]"`.

```js
<template>
    <a :href="linkTo" class="dropdown-item" :class="[{'bg-red': conditionA}, customClass]" :tabindex="disabled ? '-1' : undefined" @click="click">
        <slot></slot>
    </a>
</template>
```